# Template for MySQL Table Creation - Python

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-python

I am creating one table per user in my database and later storing data specific to that user. Since I have 100+ users, I was looking to automate the table creation process in my Python code.

Much like how I can automate a row insertion in a table, I tried to automate table insertion.
**Row insertion code:**

```
PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE = (
    "INSERT INTO metadata "
    "(to_date, customer_name, subdomain, internal_users)"
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
```

**How I use it:**

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Opening csv table to feed data
with open('/csv-table-path', 'r') as weeklyInsight:
    reader = csv.DictReader(weeklyInsight)
    for dataDict in reader:
        # Changing date to %m/%d/%Y format
        to_date = dataDict['To'][:5] + "20" + dataDict['To'][5:]
        payload_data = (
            datetime.strptime(to_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
            dataDict['CustomerName'],
            dataDict['Subdomain'],
            dataDict['InternalUsers']
        )
        cursor.execute(PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE, payload_data)
```

How can I create a `'TABLE_TEMPLATE'` that can be executed in a similar way to create a table?

I wish to create it such that I can execute the template code from my `cursor` after replacing certain fields with others.

```
TABLE_TEMPLATE = (
    "  CREATE TABLE '{customer_name}' (" # Change customer_name for new table 
    "'To' DATE NOT NULL,"
    "'Users' INT(11) NOT NULL,"
    "'Valid' VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB"
)
```

Comment: I believe I found a solution using the `format()` function in Python. Finally! It works!

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to create a table for each user I suggest changing your design. It is usually _much_ easier and cleaner to simply create a single users table.

Comment: I hope whatever value you're passing into `format()` doesn't come from the users themselves. If it does you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Chris I am hoping to store the weekly numbers of InternalUsers as separate rows in each table for each company/user and later use this data to graph out the increase/decrease of InternalUsers in a nice UI. All data coming is coming from offline pre-created Excel sheets. This is all server side. I wanted to store lists of the InternalUser numbers in each row as though a row was a user. However, I cannot seem to create and later add to a list in mySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical¹ need to create a separate table for each client. It is simpler and cleaner to have a single table, e.g.

```sql
-- A simple users table; you probably already have something like this
create table users (
  id integer not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(50),

  primary key (id)
);

create table weekly_numbers (
  id integer not null auto_increment,

  -- By referring to the id column of our users table we link each
  -- row with a user
  user_id integer references users(id),

  `date` date not null,
  user_count integer(11) not null,

  primary key (id)
);
```

Let's add some sample data:

```sql
insert into users (id, name)
values (1, 'Kirk'),
  (2, 'Picard');

insert into weekly_numbers (user_id, `date`, user_count)
values (1, '2017-06-13', 5),
  (1, '2017-06-20', 7),
  (2, '2017-06-13', 3),
  (1, '2017-06-27', 10),
  (2, '2017-06-27', 9),
  (2, '2017-06-20', 12);
```

Now let's look at Captain Kirk's numbers:

```sql
select `date`, user_count
from weekly_numbers

-- By filtering on user_id we can see one user's numbers
where user_id = 1
order by `date` asc;
```

¹There may be *business* reasons to keep your users' data separate. A common use case would be isolating your clients' data, but in that case a separate *database per client* seems like a better fit.

Comment: Just recently, I discussed my use-case with my senior. He gave precisely this idea! You read minds, my dear friend.